# Get the interface type of an interface proxy created without target

Tags: c#, castle-dynamicproxy

Considering model below:

```
public interface IFooBase
{
    void DoSomething();
}

public interface IFoo : IFooBase
{
}
```

A Castle.DynamicProxy interceptor:

```
public class Proxy : IInterceptor
{
    public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
    {
        // Here need to know from which interface the proxy 
        // is generate (IFooBase or IFoo).
    }
}
```

And the proxies of IFooBase and IFoo generated using CreateInterfaceProxyWithoutTarget in the program.cs:

```
var generator = new ProxyGenerator();
var proxy = new Proxy();
var fooBase = generator.CreateInterfaceProxyWithoutTarget<IFooBase>(proxy);
var foo = generator.CreateInterfaceProxyWithoutTarget<IFoo>(proxy);
fooBase.DoSomething();
foo.DoSomething();
```

Inside the **Intercept** method, I need know from which interface type (IFooBase or IFoo) the proxy is generated. The only option I know is **invocation.Method.DeclaringType** which of course always returns FooBase type.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code i use name of interface , you can compare type of them

```
public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
{

    var types = invocation.GetType().GetInterfaces();
    bool hasIFoo = false;
    bool hasIFooBase = false;
    foreach (var type in types)
    {
        if (type.Name == "IFoo")
        {
            hasIFoo = true;
        }
        if (type.Name == "IFooBase")
        {
            hasIFooBase = true;
        }
    }
    if (hasIFoo && hasIFooBase)
        Console.WriteLine("Implement IFooBase");
    else if (hasIFoo)
        Console.WriteLine("Implement IFoo");
    else
        Console.WriteLine("Implement Nothing");

}
```

Comment: I have tried it already. The invocation.GetType().GetInterfaces() returns only an IInvocation type.

Comment: IInvocation  must implement one of IBaseFoo or IFoo to  GetInterfaces() return them

Comment: I found the answer and posted it. I should use invocation.Proxy.GetType().GetInterfaces(). Although I knew your solution already but your post rang a bell to find the answer by myself.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer by myself and share it here.

The code below for the interception of fooBase.DoSomething() returns **IFooBase** and for the foo.DoSomething() returns **IFoo** and **IFooBase**.

```
invocation.Proxy.GetType().GetInterfaces()
```